# How does binary sum use O(log n) space?

Tags: algorithm, recursion

I am reading a data structure and algorithms book and, in a recursion chapter, I encounter the following algorithm:

```
def binary_sum(S, start, stop):
    if start >= stop:
        return 0
    elif start == stop-1:
        return S[start]
    else:
        mid = (start + stop) // 2
        return binary_sum(S, start, mid) + binary_sum(S, mid, stop)
```

The author argues that this is more efficient than linear sum:

```
def linear_sum(S, n):
    if n == 0:
        return 0
    else:
        return linear_sum(S, n-1) + S[n-1]
```

Because at each step of iteration, we halve the range we sum (split in the middle), meaning that we take up `O(log n)` space. Image below:

My understanding however, is that when we recurse, the call to a recursive step suspends execution, and its activation record remains in memory. Doesn't that mean that we actually take up `2^n` space of memory with binary_sum?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: @RyanVincent The `linear_sum` is not implemented tail recursively since it does not use an accumulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is correct because the depth of the call-stack is bounded logarithmically.

In the example you provided, there can be at most 4 calls on the stack at each time. They do not all hang around. By the time we start executing `1:2` we have already finished `0:1` and removed it from the stack. Likewise, we finish `0:2` and then begin `2:4`. While we execute `2:4` we do not use any space for `0:2` because it is done. We also don't use any space for future calls such as `4:8` until we finish what we are currently working on.

Comment: Thanks :) This makes sense.